# How to select drop list items depending on another drop list choice in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, form-helpers

I want to filter a drop list items depending on choice item from another drop list

```
<%= form_tag("/myAdmin", method: "post") do %>
    <%= label_tag(:role_id, "Role: ")%>
    <%= select_tag('Role', options_for_select(Role.all.map(&:name)))  %> <br/>
    <%= label_tag(:school_id, "School: ")%>
    <%= select_tag('School', options_for_select(School.all.map(&:name) )) %> <br/>
    <%= label_tag(:grade_id, "Grade: ")%>
    <%= @grade = Grade.all
        @grade1 = @grade.map {|a| if a.school_id == :school_id a}
        select_tag('Grade', options_for_select(@grade1.map(&:name) ))  %> <br/>

<%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

here's a form that contains 3 drop lists.

I want to filter the grade list according the chosen school..

The grade model has { school_id and name attributes } and the school model has { organization_id and name attributes }

how can I do this?

Comment: You have to do it on the client side, using javascript.

Comment: I want to perform it using Erb not javascript

Comment: But do you want to update grades when you select a school in the browser?

Comment: yes, I wanna to update/filter the grade drop list after selecting the school

Comment: This means you need to use javascript.

Comment: Is this the only solution I have now?

Comment: Yes you need to do using javascript.

Comment: It's the only general direction, yes. You want client-side functionality - you need client-side tech. ERb is server-side tech.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I tried to perform it using js but I failed every time. I used this tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus . 
and searched for other approaches. 
could u plz help me?